# Getting a list of frames from an input video with ffmpeg as pictures

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying to extract a small number of frames from a video, like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf 'select=eq(n\,1395)+eq(n\,2790)+eq(n\,4185)+eq(n\,5580)' \
  'img%01d.jpg'
```

However, what I get, is that ffmpeg extracts all the frames in the video and not only the ones I want. What could I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may add `-vsync 0` or `-fps_mode:v passthrough` argument:

For newer version of FFmpeg add `-fps_mode`:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -fps_mode:v passthrough -vf "select='eq(n\,1395)+eq(n\,2790)+eq(n\,4185)+eq(n\,5580)'" img%01d.jpg`

For older version of FFmpeg use `vsync`:

`ffmpeg -vsync 0 -i input.mp4 -vf "select='eq(n\,1395)+eq(n\,2790)+eq(n\,4185)+eq(n\,5580)'" img%01d.jpg`

---

When executing FFmpeg, there is a warning message: "More than 1000 frames duplicated".
The output images are not all the input video frames, but a lot of duplications of the same frame.
Multiple duplications of frame 1395, then duplications of frame 2790...
FFmpeg duplicates the frames for achieving constant output frame rate.

The reason is that the default `fps_mode` is `auto (-1)` that applies *"Chooses between cfr and vfr depending on muxer capabilities."*.
`cfr` is selected, so *"Frames will be duplicated and dropped to achieve exactly the requested constant frame rate"*.
For achieving constant "(output) frame, the last selected frame is duplicated, until the next selected frame...

---

Testing:

Build 10fps input video with frame counter (for testing):
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 10 -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=6000 -vf setpts=N/10/TB -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p input.mp4`.

Execute:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -fps_mode:v passthrough -vf "select=eq(n\,1395)+eq(n\,2790)+eq(n\,4185)+eq(n\,5580)" img%01d.jpg`

The output is 4 JPEG images:
`img1.jpg`, `img2.jpg`, `img3.jpg`, `img4.jpg`:
[image], [image], [image], [image]

Tested using FFmpeg version 5.1.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev under Windows 10.

Comment: I see a wizard...